# Python 2.7: Format a list within a list using for loops

Tags: python, python-2.7

Input:

```
data = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['001', 'ddd', 'eee', '10'], ['002', 'fff', 'ggg', '20']]
```

Expected output:

```
data = ['A', 'B', 'C'], [1, 'ddd', 'eee', 10], [2, 'fff', 'ggg', 20]]
```

- Convert columns with numerical values from strings to integers (with quotes around the numbers removed

I have attempted with the below code but I am getting this error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: A

Could anyone point out my mistake?

```
formatted = []
for row in data:
    new_row = []
    for i, col in enumerate(row):
        if i != [1,2]:
            new_row.append(col)
            new_row.append(float(col))
    formatted.append(new_row)

print formatted
```

Comment: Is it possible to have a list with more than one element in it without commas?

Comment: "Remove commas after each list"? There is no such data type for what you're asking.

Comment: "Could anyone point out my mistake" - What can we possibly point out, that `could not convert string to float` hasn't pointed out already???

Comment: @goodvibration Ok, then i guess i will edit the post to remove the first critieria

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'pythonic' way to do this is to try converting each element to an integer, and fall back to keeping the string in case of failure.

```
formatted = []
for row in data:
    new_row = []
    for elem in row:
        try:
            new_row.append(int(elem))
        except ValueError:
            new_row.append(elem)
    formatted.append(new_row)

print formatted
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
def to_float(s):
    try:
        return float(s)
    except:
        return s

[[to_float(s) for s in row] for row in data]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `i`, an integer, will never be equal to [1,2], a list.
What you meant to say/write is:

`if i not in [1,2]:`

Edit:
I forgot the first row.
Since your first row is not like the others, either handle it differently (not recommended), or use one of the other answers (recommended)

Comment: He might have meant that, but I don't think it fixes his code!

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a lambda function with a condition using map:

```
for i,d in enumerate(data):
    data[i] = map(lambda x: float(x) if x.isdigit() else x, d)
```

`map` applies the lambda function on every subelement of d. If the element is a string representing a digit, it applies conversion using `float`, if it is not, it leaves the whole string as it is. It directly replaces the sublist in data.

In Python 3.X the result of map would need to be explicitly converted to a list, i.e. `data[i] = list(map())`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using json and regex as follows:

```
import json, re

data = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['001', 'ddd', 'eee', '10'], ['002', 'fff', 'ggg', '20']]
data = json.dumps(data)
data = json.loads(re.sub(r'"0*(\d+)"', r'\1', data)

print (data)
```

Output:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], [1, 'ddd', 'eee', 10], [2, 'fff', 'ggg', 20]]
```

You also mentioned you wanted to remove commas after each list, well here is one way:

```
data = reduce(lambda oldList, newList: oldList + newList, data, [])
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'C', 1, 'ddd', 'eee', 10, 2, 'fff', 'ggg', 20]
```